# Add Vue.js event on window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

Vue.js allow apply event on element:

```html
<div id="app">
   <button @click="play()">Play</button>
</div>
```

But how to apply event on `window` object? it is not in DOM.

for example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div @mousedown="startDrag()" @mousemove="move($event)">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

in this example, how to listen mousemove event on `window` ?

Answer (score 78):

You should just do it manually during the creation and destruction of the component

```
...
created: function() {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove',this.move);
},
destroyed: function() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.move);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. The answer was helpful. Do I need destroyed if I have to add the listener in the main parent component on App level?

Comment: Destroying registered listener isn't required on the main component of your project unless it might be embedded in more complex setup with your vue application being just one part of the view. Thus, unregistering everything is best practice in all situations to make your code future proof.

Answer (score 16):

Jeff's answer is perfect and should be the accepted answer. Helped me out a lot!

Although, I have something to add that caused me some headache. When defining the `move` method it's important to use the `function()` constructor and not use ES6 arrow function `=>` if you want access to `this` on the child component. `this` doesn't get passed through to arrow functions from where it's called but rather referrers to its surroundings where it is defined. This is called lexical scope.

Here is my implementation with the called method (here called `keyDown` instead of `move`) included:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    SudokuBoard
  },
  methods: {
    keyDown: function () {
      const activeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0]
      if (activeElement && !isNaN(event.key) && event.key > 0) {
        activeElement.innerHTML = event.key
      }
    }

  },

  created: function () {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown)
  },

  destroyed: function () {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown)
  }
}
```

To be extra clear, The method below doesn't have access to `this` and can't for example reach the data or props object on your child component.

```
methods: { 
    keyDown: () => {
      //no 'this' passed. Can't access child's context 
      }
```

Comment: Your example isn't even using `this` in the `keyDown()` function. I doubt `this` is pointing to the component there anyways. If you actually need access to the component it is safest to bind the handler or use arrow function on registration. But in that case you have to save that bound/arrow function as a property of your component for use on removeEventListener() to prevent memory leak, too.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the **[vue-global-events](https://github.com/shentao/vue-global-events)** library.

```
<GlobalEvents @mousemove="move"/>
```

It also supports event modifiers like `@keydown.up.ctrl.prevent="handler"`.

Answer (score 4):

This is for someone landed here searching solution for `nuxt.js`:

I was creating sticky header for one of my projects & faced issue to make `window.addEventListener` work.

First of all, not sure why but `window.addEventListener` doesn't work with `created` or `beforeCreate` hooks, hence I am using `mounted`.

```
<template lang="pug">
  header(:class="{ 'fixed-header': scrolled }")
    nav menu here
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AppHeader',

  data() {
    return { scrolled: false };
  },

  mounted() {
    // Note: do not add parentheses () for this.handleScroll
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },

  methods: {
    handleScroll() {
      this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 50;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: mounted / unmounted should be always preferred over created / destroyed to support SSR. I guess, this applied in your case, too.

Answer (score 4):

I found that using `window.addEventListener` no longer worked as I expected with Vue 3. It appears that the function is wrapped by Vue now. Here's a workaround:

```js
...
created()
{
  document.addEventListener.call(window, "mousemove", event =>
  {
    ...
  });
}
...
```

The important part is `document.addEventListener.call(window`, what we're doing is to take the unwrapped `addEventListener` from `document` and then call it on the `window` Object.

Comment: This does not seem to work in the Vue 3 CDN version