# Is there any way to 'watch' for localstorage in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

I'm attempting to watch for localstorage:

Template:

```
<p>token - {{token}}</p>
```

Script:

```
computed: {
  token() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
}
```

But it doesn't change, when `token` changes. Only after refreshing the page.

Is there a way to solve this without using Vuex or state management?

Comment: `localStorage` is not reactive, vuejs can detect changes in properties which were created in the instance.

Comment: If you can explain why you want to do this someone can help!

Answer (score 44):

`localStorage` is not reactive but I needed to "watch" it because my app uses localstorage and didn't want to re-write everything so here's what I did using `CustomEvent`.

I would dispatch a `CustomEvent` whenever you add something to storage

```js
localStorage.setItem('foo-key', 'data to store')

window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('foo-key-localstorage-changed', {
  detail: {
    storage: localStorage.getItem('foo-key')
  }
}));
```

Then where ever you need to watch it do:

```js
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('foo-key-localstorage-changed', (event) => {
    this.data = event.detail.storage;
  });
},
data() {
  return {
    data: null,
  }
}
```

Comment: This + https://stackoverflow.com/a/53596376/12397235 were two shining beacons in the darkness for me.

Comment: Another nice part of this, is that you can invoke a vue-based response from a vanilla js object.

Comment: wow man this is just very perfect way of handling things like this.

Comment: This only works if the change is made from the same tab and if that's the case, every other event bus implementation would work as well and be superior to obscure custom DOM events.

Comment: Much recommended solution. Thanks for this

Answer (score 31):

Sure thing! The best practice in my opinion is to use the [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/get) / [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/set) syntax to wrap the localstorage in.

Here is a working example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  {{token}}
  <button @click="token++"> + </button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      get token() {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') || 0;
      },
      set token(value) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', value);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

And a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djsj8dku/1/).

Comment: Good alternate, but in the case compiler keep on hitting again and again one hit to check whether value changes or not.

Comment: Interestingly, eslint gives me the error `vue/no-dupe-keys` on the second entry (getter or setter).  I suppressed it with `// eslint-disable-line vue/no-dupe-keys` which seems to work.

Comment: Also, localStorage seems to convert ints to strings so I needed to run `return parseInt(localStorage.getItem('userSessionIndex') || 0)` for it to work.  Others may or may not run into this problem.

Comment: @MattClimbs Everyone will run into that because that's how Local Storage work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: @Cobaltway Do you know, why it does not work very well using the same logic inside computed? If using inside data like you did, everything works as expected.

Comment: The only reason this would work is because every time it is clicked, the get value is called to retrieve then the set is called to modify. It is not reactive when other sources modify the localstorage.

Answer (score 10):

The VueJs site has a page about this.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html

They provide an example.
Given this html template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    My name is <input v-model="name">
  </div>
<template>
```

They provide this use of the lifecycle `mounted` method and a watcher.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.name) {
      this.name = localStorage.name;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name(newName) {
      localStorage.name = newName;
    }
  }
});
```

The `mounted` method assures you the `name` is set from local storage if it already exists, and the watcher allows your component to react whenever the name in local storage is modified. This works fine for when data in local storage is added or changed, but Vue will not react if someone wipes their local storage manually.

Comment: While simplistic this is what i was looking for as well as the link spoke to more complex use. Thanks

Comment: I think that it only works one way when 'name' is changed, but not from other side (when 'localstorage.name' is changed).

Comment: Yes. The watch is only set up on the `name` property in the app, not the actual localstorage object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512129/how-to-save-state-variables-to-the-browser-localstorage-using-vue-js-vuex-c

Comment: How to do it with `createApp`?

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: vue-persistent-state is no longer maintained. Fork or look else where if it doesn't fit your bill as is.

If you want to avoid boilerplate (getter/setter-syntax), use [vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state) to get reactive persistent state.

For example:

```
import persistentState from 'vue-persistent-state';  

const initialState = {
  token: ''  // will get value from localStorage if found there
};
Vue.use(persistentState, initialState);

new Vue({
  template: '<p>token - {{token}}</p>'
})
```

Now `token` is available as data in all components and Vue instances. Any changes to `this.token` will be stored in localStorage, and you can use `this.token` as you would in a vanilla Vue app.

The plugin is basically watcher and `localStorage.set`. You can read the code [here](https://github.com/arve0/vue-persistent-state/blob/master/index.js). It

1. adds a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to make `initialState` available in all Vue instances, and
2. watches for changes and stores them.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of [vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state).

Comment: That repository has been archived. Its recommended not to use this solution anymore.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in two ways,

1. by using [vue-ls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-ls) and then adding the listener on storage keys, with

   ```
       Vue.ls.on('token', callback)
   ```

   or

   ```
       this.$ls.on('token', callback)
   ```
2. by using storage event listener of DOM:

   ```
       document.addEventListener('storage', storageListenerMethod);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage or sessionStorage are not reactive. Thus you can't put a watcher on them. A solution would be to store value from a store state if you are using Vuex for example.
Ex:

```
SET_VALUE:(state,payload)=> {
    state.value = payload
    localStorage.setItem('name',state.value)
    or
    sessionStorage.setItem('name',state.value)
  }
```