# VueJS - how to watch a value in localStorage?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a `nav` component that needs to only be shown when there is a token stored in `localStorage`. When that token is deleted from `localStorage` the `nav` component needs to notice that change and hide itself.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Are you in control of setting the token to localStorage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local Storage is not reactive, so you need to store your token in some place that is. I assume your token is being set and deleted by the application. If so, the best way to handle this is to use state like Vuex ([see Vue State Management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html)).

**Option 1**

If you are using local storage in order to retain the token between multiple browser sessions, the best option is to just set the token in Vuex then use [Vuex persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) to sync Vuex to local or session storage. The plugin will retrieve it again when you need to re-establish state.

**Option 2**

If you need it set in the local storage directly, you should include in your mutations to set/unset the localStorage when you are changing the state. This will keep your localStorage and State in sync.

For example using Vuex, if you are receiving a token in a response you can then call a Mutation to set it in Vuex state as well as set it to localStorage:

```
SET_TOKEN(state, payload){
    state.token = payload.token 
    localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token)
}
```

You can then easily watch the Vuex state. Depending on how your Vuex is set up, it may be something like: this.$store.state.token

Answer (score 1):

Hiding your navbar should not be related with setting localStorage. I would expect something like this:

```
function hideNav() {
  // Inform the application that the nav should hide
  dispatchHideNavAction() 

  // Change localStorage
  deleteTokenFromLocalStorage()
}
```

If instead, your problem is in hiding the nav when the token is deleted from another window, then you can use [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent):

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'mytoken' && e.newValue === null) {
    hideNav()
  }
});
```

**NB**: this won't work within the same window, but only if the token is deleted from another tab.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting the token yourself, store the token in a global state and persist it with [vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state). The plugin is suitable for simple apps, where state management with vuex is not needed.

For example

```
import persistentStorage from 'vue-persistent-storage';

const initialState = {
  token: 0  // overwritten if found in localStorage
};
Vue.use(persistentStorage, initialState);

new Vue({
  data: {
    sections: ['Home', 'Edit']
    // we get `token` from persistentStorage
  },
  template: `<nav>
      <a 
        v-for="(section, i) in sections" 
        class="{ active: token === i }"
      >
        {{section}}
      </a>
    </nav>`,
  methods: {
    changeToken: function () {
      // you may change token from other Vue instances too
      this.token = this.token++
      // wrap
      this.token = this.token % this.sections.length
    }
  }
})
```

`token` is available as data in all components and Vue instances. Any changes to `this.token` will be stored in localStorage, and you can use `this.token` as you would in a vanilla Vue app.

The plugin is basically watcher and `localStorage.set`. You can read the code [here](https://github.com/arve0/vue-persistent-state/blob/master/index.js). It

1. adds a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to make `initialState` available in all Vue instances, and
2. watches for changes and stores them.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of [vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state).

Comment: what If I want to use it with sessionStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Using `CustomEvent` and listening to it can help you make localStorage "reactive", answered in similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178486/6714319