# Reload component with vue-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, components, vue-router

I have a project with Vuejs and Vue-Router. When a user pay in (login) system, the server return a file Json with token, username and first name, this file is stored  in localstorage for be used in following requests. The first name is used in layout for show a message welcome in the navbar. After logout, localstorage is cleared and the problem is here, when other user pay in the message welcome not reload with new first name.

```
<v-chip>{{bienvenida}}</v-chip>
```

---

```
computed: {
  bienvenida() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    return user ? `Bienvenido ${user.firstName}` : "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS - how to watch a value in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865172/vuejs-how-to-watch-a-value-in-localstorage)

Comment: I would use Vuex and vuex-persist. You bind reactively to the vuex getter and let vuex-persist handle storing the state in localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

The LocalStorage is not reactive, so the computed property does not react on a change of the localStorage. There are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873478/3233827) to circumvent this, but the easiest is, to watch an internal property and just persist the values to the localStorage too.

One proper way to do this is to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) (official state management of Vue) to store your data to a Vuex store. There is then [a Vuex plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) to persist all of the store or parts of it in the local or session storage. The Vuex store is reactive, so you can just watch changes to the store in your computed property.