# Is there a way to bind LocalStorage with a reactive variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, reactive-programming, vuejs3

I use [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist some content of my Vue3 app. Today, I just write to `LocalStorage` any changes in the content I want to preserve and read from that contact in specific cases (an interval, or some other trigger).

The last part is not optimal because I need to have complex logic about how to make the `LocalStorage` → app update (`LocalStorage` can be updated by "something else", and this update should reflected in the app)

The solution would be to **bind the content of `LocalStorage` with a reactive variable**, which would natively bring two advantages:

- any change in the variable or `LocalStorage` is reflected in the other one
- changes are naturally persistent

**Question 1**: Is this something that is possible (Vue3 and a modern browser)?

**Question 2**: I recently heard about [`FileSystem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) which seems to be a possible alternative to `LocalStorage`, but I do not know it enough to assess whether it could be more suited to solve my problem?

*Note: there is a similar question ([How to make data from localStorage reactive in Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015101/how-to-make-data-from-localstorage-reactive-in-vue-js)) but it does not cover Vue3 and the possible use of `FileSystem`. The answer is basically "it is not possible natively. I will mark it as a duplicate if this is still the case.*

Comment: This is usually done with global store, because LS is global either. And there are ready to use solutions for Vuex, etc

Comment: @EstusFlask: I do have a global store (for other reasons), the problem is how to do the reactive binding between the two.

Comment: With Vuex plugin. It uses `storage` event internally.

Comment: @EstusFlask: I just have a basic knowledge of Vuex (I checked if it was useful for my project by reading the docs) - so sorry if the question is obvious bur: does Vuex manage internally the LocalStorage events to mutate the states? I cannot find anything about that in its docs.

Comment: It's not. But it has everything to make it possible. E.g. https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate There's a lot of similar Vuex questions that cover this

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the feedback. It is not really a binding between the two entities, rather a way to persist data between page reloads (and yes, there are several libs that do it I saw in various places). I guess that a true biding is not directly doable then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, if you are updating localStorage at one place, it should also update on other pages.

I never tried this, but I can think of two approaches.

- where you can listen to storage event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event
  this has some limitations, please check.
- Create an `Event` and attach it to the window & whenever you are updating localStorage dispatch the custom event and on listening to the custom event, fetch the data from localStorage.