# How to make data from localStorage reactive?

Tags: vuejs3

I'm storing some data in the `localStorage` but it's only correct when I refresh the page. I assume this is because the variable is not marked as reactive using `ref` but it still doesn't work.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    const isLoggedIn = ref(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true');
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make data from localStorage reactive in Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015101/how-to-make-data-from-localstorage-reactive-in-vue-js)

Comment: @vixducis possibly but it's half-a-decade old. I'm new to Vue so not sure what's best practice or even what my options are but ty for the link.

Comment: You cannot use localStorage as a reactive reference. What you can do is use it as a persistence layer. Nothing has changed in this area

Comment: @Phil is there something else I should be doing instead? Any libraries/plugins that have this functionality?

Comment: https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/

Comment: I recomend you to use a normal reactive variable (I think a very intuitive aproach are signals: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#connection-to-signals) then create a method that both updates the signal and updates the local storage, this way both values will be synced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a read/write computed property

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { computed } from 'vue'

    const isLoggedIn = computed({
      get: () => localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true',
      set: (v) => localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', v)
    }
</script>
```