# Computed property react to localstorage change

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I'm saving an array into local storage

and adding/removing from the array like.

I want the count of the array to update in the component as and when new items get added to the array in localstorage

I am using a computed property:

```
 numOfCodes: {
      // getter
      get: function() {
        let storageItems = localStorage.getItem("items");
        if (storageItems) {
          var items = JSON.parse(storageItems);
          return items.length;
        }
        return 0;
      }
    }
```

The count is not changing as expected. it remains the same.

I have tried using vuex, but still have the issue. the goal is having the value react to the localstorage change

Comment: Salam offered a nice solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178486/4177565

Answer (score 1):

The localStorage does not share the reactivity system of Vue. This whole process is handled by Vue itself. See also [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). I think you should be able to manually trigger a re-render by forcing Vue to update all of its components using [forceUpdate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate). However, keep in mind that you would have to trigger the re-render whenever you update the localStorage or whenever you expect it to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution to this would be to use vuex, I've mocked up an example below:

On your component:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        itemsCount: 'mockLocalStorage/itemsCount'
    })
},

created() {
    this.setItems(...);
},

methods: {
   ...mapActions({
       setItems: 'mockLocalStorage/setItems'
   })
}
```

In vuex:

```
state = {
    items: []
};

getters = {
    itemsCount: state => state.items.length
};

actions: {
    setItems({ commit }, items) {
        localStorage.setItem('items', items);
        commit('setItems', items);
    }
};
```

`this.itemsCount` would then be reactive in your component, and you could create a few more actions to add and remove individual items.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

```
props: ['storageItems', 'itemsLength'],
watch: {
    storageItems: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.storageItems = newVal
        this.itemsLength = newVal.length
    }
}
```