# How to get the lastest number without refresh in another component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, local-storage, vuejs3

There are two components current using **Helloworld** component save the value to localStorage and display the value from display from **New** component to display it. I tried using computed to get the data but it's still need to refresh to get the lastest value.

Here the example feel free to test or solve the problem >>> [Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/localstoragetest-isl6k9)

```
computed: {
token: {
  get: function () {
    return this.tokenValue;
  },
  set: function (id_token) {
    this.tokenValue = id_token;
    localStorage.setItem("Num1", id_token);
  },
},
```

},

Comment: Vue is not reactive to local storage. Vue has its own library `vuex` to manage the storage. https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: This answer might help you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755906/computed-property-react-to-localstorage-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch custom event and listen to that event in other components.

So in `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
 addnum() {
   localStorage.setItem("Num1", this.number++);
   window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('num-changed', {
     detail: {
       num: localStorage.getItem('Num1')
     }
   }));
 },
```

in `New.vue`:

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('num-changed', (event) => {
    this.tokenvalue = event.detail.num;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for make this simple answer which take me 2 days to get the answer ^_^