# How to save "state" variables to the browser localStorage using Vue.js + Vuex (createStore)

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, state, vuex

I am trying to load (using `mounted()`) and save (with the `watch: {...}` method) to / from the localStorage.

The two variables i am trying to save to the localstorage are 'categories' and 'locations'.

I just cannot get it triggered for some reason. I have never done this using vue.js/vuex.

all examples I have found use the `data: {}` object in "regular" components. In my example I am trying to load and save to the state variables.
Please help. I have pasted the whole vuex `createStore` object (*project/src/store/index.js*):

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
    state: {
        categories: [ "Food", "Bars", "Parks"],
        locations: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        addCategory(state, newCategory) {
            state.categories.push(newCategory)
        }, 
        removeCategory(state, i) {
            state.categories.splice(i, 1);
        }, 
        saveCategory(state, data) {
            state.categories[data.item] = data.text
        }, 
        addLocation(state, data) {
            state.locations.push(data)
        },
        deleteLocation(state, i) {
            state.locations.splice(i, 1);
        }, 
        saveLocation(state, data) {
            state.locations[data.index].categories = data.item
        },

    },
    watch:{
        categories(newCategories) {
            console.log(newCategories)
            localStorage.categories = JSON.stringify(newCategories)
        }, 
        locations(newLocations) {
            console.log(newLocations)
            localStorage.locations = JSON.stringify(newLocations)
        }
    },
    actions: {
    },
    modules: {
    }, 
    mounted() {
        console.log(localStorage.categories)
        console.log(localStorage.locations)
        if (localStorage.categories) {
            this.categories = JSON.parse(localStorage.categories)
            if (localStorage.locations) 
                this.locations = JSON.parse(localStorage.locations)
        }

    }
})
```

Edit:

tried:

```
"state.categories" (newCategories) {
    console.log(newCategories)
    localStorage.categories = JSON.stringify(newCategories)
}, 
"state.locations" (newLocations) {
    console.log(newLocations)
    localStorage.locations = JSON.stringify(newLocations)
}
```

no errors but doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the link with the great explanation:
https://www.mikestreety.co.uk/blog/vue-js-using-localstorage-with-the-vuex-store/

in my `/project/src/main.js` file:

```
store.subscribe( (mutation, state) => {
    localStorage.setItem('categories', JSON.stringify(state.categories));  
    localStorage.setItem('locations', JSON.stringify(state.locations));  
})
```

in my `/project/src/App.vue` file I added the following (although I'm pretty sure using "mounted()" will work as well:

```
beforeMount() {
    this.$store.commit('initialiseVars')
},
```

and added a mutation method to `/project/src/store/index.js`:

```
initialiseVars(state) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('categories')) {
        state.categories = JSON.parse(localStorage.categories)
        if (localStorage.getItem('locations')) 
            state.locations = JSON.parse(localStorage.locations)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to move the mounted and watch code to your App.vue as that component is always loaded as long as your web-app is loaded.

Also for your watch write it like this:

```
"state.categories" () {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: no errors but didn't save anything (or trigger my console.log)

Comment: I tried doing this in a few variations. my main.js looks like this: `createApp(App).use(store).mount('#app')`. and in my App.vue file I have the initial Vue. I added watch and mounted there and they do not reach the state.

Comment: Are you certain your Vuex store is loaded correctly? Trying to console.log "this.state"

Does your Vue initialization look like this:

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");