# Window event listener in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

If I add window event listeners like `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => { ...  })` in the `created()` method, do I still need to remove the listeners in `beforeDestroy()`?

And second question: is it possible to add window events using Vue functions rather than `window.addEventListener`?

Comment: 1st: As you want, there is nothing related to `vue.js`. 2nd: I don't think so. (there may be component but I personally don't like this kind of things)

Comment: I think it's duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993834/add-vue-js-event-on-window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Vue.js event on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993834/add-vue-js-event-on-window)