# How to add window.addEventListener and remove window.removeEventListener in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add window.addEventListener in vue js file.

```
 window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log(event, ' i am here');
 });
```

I have added this in mounted() function.

Now, I need to remove this in destroyed method but somehow I am not able to do it.

```
window.removeEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log(event, ' i am here');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Vue.js event on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993834/add-vue-js-event-on-window)

Answer (score 4):

Ok So I have created a fiddle that will show you how to remove and add the message handler and how to post message it's here:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    addHandler: function() {
        window.addEventListener('message', this.eventListenerExample);
    },
    removeHandler: function(){
        window.removeEventListener('message', this.eventListenerExample);
    },
    postMessage: function() {
        window.postMessage("This is a message ");
        },
    eventListenerExample: function(event){
        console.log(event, ' i am here');
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.addHandler();
    },
  destroyed: function() {
    this.removeHanlder();
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ob1pLd7z/8/

Note here that the function is part of this vue instance and the function itself is added and removed rather than using an inline function like you originally showed.

Answer (score 3):

I am happy to read that you want to clear/remove listener after component destroy

```js
  mounted() {
    const listener = () => {}
    const event = 'message'
    window.addEventListener(event, listener)
    this.$once('hook:destroyed', () => {
      window.removeEventListener(event, listener)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `destroyed()` or `beforeDestroy()` to remove the event listener.

To add event use `mounted()` like this,

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('event', listener);
}
```

ex:

```
mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.navigateMovements);
    }
```

and in templates main `div`,

```
<div @event='listener($event)'>
......
......
......
</div>
```

ex:

```
<div @keyup='navigateMovements($event)'>
    ......
    ......
    ......
    </div>
```

To destroy the event

```
beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('event', listener);
  }
```

ex:

```
beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.navigateMovements);
      }
```

or use `destroyed()`

```
 destroyed() {
            window.removeEventListener('event', listener);
          }
```